# EXC_BREAKPOINT crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have this setup with a navigationcontroller:

SlideMenuController -> SchedulesViewController -> Schedule ViewController -> IntervalView

The schedulesviewcontroller is a list of all the schedules.
The Schedule ViewController is the view with information about a schedule.
IntervalView is the viewcontroller with a custom pickerview selecting a value.

I can load the SchedulesViewController, and then go to the ScheduleViewcontroller, and also from there to the IntervalView.

But when I try to hit the "Back" button, it works to the Schedule ViewController, but when I want to go back to the "SchedulesViewController", it crashes

```
[IntervalView respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x7fc78d320dc0

Thread 1 > EXC_BREAKPOINT(code=EXC_I386_BPT)
```

I don't know what code to show you, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the question? what kind of answer do you want?

Comment: hey post some code of loading the IntervalView...

Answer (score 0):

This is because it your `SlideMenuController` You can not pop from `SchedulesViewController`on back click.

On back click you need to push some other view controller which you want.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, the back button is automaticly added by my navigationcontroller, so I have no control of what it does. So it should work?

Comment: add your back button on navigationcontroller and then on its back button click you should push view controller.

Comment: SlideMenuController click your going to SchedulesViewController So on back click on SchedulesViewController it is not finding any instance.

Comment: I am pretty sure this is a wrong way of doing it... As I do not have this problem with other parts, where I press "Back" to the previous viewcontroller...

Comment: it is because when your clicking back on ScheduleViewController it contains an instance of SchedulesViewController but on clicking back button on SchedulesViewController it is not finding any instance.

Comment: what is the issue doesn't it helped you ..?